# Why does pandas inconsistently work for csv data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, selenium

Why does Panda's not read values correctly?  I'm trying to find common items through vlookup in a dataframe.

Here's what is happening.
[image]

Notice the highlighted yellow values were not shown in output but were a match.

As simple example in df1 I have:

```
   A                   B                                 C         D
  gg                 vv #manually entered data          1.82    Betlink1
  Adelaide United     Newcastle Jets                    2.32    Betlink2
   aa                    aa                             aa        aa
```

In df2

```
A    B                    C                                D          E
13   Adelaide United     Newcastle Jets                    2      Betlink3
14   gg                  vv #manually entered data         1      Betlink4
```

Output:

```
AA   AB     AC     O2      AE         EW      O1      DA
14   gg     vv     1.82   Betlink1   gg v vv  1   Betlink4
```

Expected:

```
AA   AB                AC             O2      AE         EW        O1      DA
14   gg                vv             1.82   Betlink1   gg v vv    1   Betlink4
13   Adelaide United  New Castle Jets 2.32   Betlink2   (val of AC)2    Betlink3
```

Why is it doing this?  Is scraped data different? It seems pandas inconsistently vlooks up data. How do I edit the pandas data in a csv so that it does not do this.

Is there a way to correct this through scraping in selenium?
Selenium:

```
import csv
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.get('https://www.betfair.com.au/exchange/plus/football')
time.sleep(7)


langs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.runners > li:nth-child(1)")
langs_text = []

for lang in langs:
    langs_text.append(lang.text)


directory = 'C:/331.csv'
with open(directory, 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in zip(langs_text):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Or is this more likely a pandas issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
time.sleep(0)
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\33.csv',
                  index_col=False,
                  usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3],
                  names=["EW", "WE", "DA", "DD"],
                  header=None)



df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\33.csv',
                  index_col=False,
                  usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  names=["AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE"],
                  header=None)



ZF= df1.EW.str.split(' v ').apply(lambda x : [y.split(' ')[0] for y in x]).apply(' v '.join)
df1['EW'] = ZF

df1['EW'] = df1['EW'] + ' v ' + df1['WE']

df1['WE'] = df1['DA']
df1['DA'] = df1['DD']
print(df1.head())


df2['EW'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']
#print(df2.head())
#df2['EW'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']


df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='EW')
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'WE':'O1','AD':'O2'})
df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fill_value=0)
```

I tried this with vlookup formulas in Excel and no such issue.

I assume csv data is to be handled a certain way and perhaps scraping is not even the issue but rather how you handle it with pandas.  Strangely, sometimes the job works, other times it does not.  Is there a way to address this?  I've looked at the cells and there don't appear to be any gaps so I'm at a loss as to why it does not find a match.

The csv file could be corrupt but unlikely as its a newly created csv each time.

[File 1](https://dropfile.to/k8SAbE0)

[File 2](https://dropfile.to/eGsnTMF)

Comment: If I manually enter the data, it seems to pick up on new matches.  So there's  my first clue.  It could be my code is not working but works for manually entered data.  Strange.

Comment: Is possible see your file data, e.g. upload files or send them to my email?

Comment: @jezrael Sure can, I've sent you my exact csv files

Comment: @jezrael Sorry for delay, been doing some more testing.  Type in in ctrl f: Adelaide United and you'll see exact issue I talk about and that Adelaide United v Newcastle jets is in Betfair and Centrebet

Comment: @jezrael UHHHH.. I see the problem I think now.  It was indeed the code.

Comment: Yes, what was wrong?

Comment: @jezrael ZF= df1.EW.str.split(' v ').apply(lambda x : [y.split(' ')[0] for y in x]).apply(' v '.join)
df1['EW'] = ZF Should be removed

Comment: @jezrael Hmm.. wait not sure if that is solution as it didn't fix.  I did get it working once.  Wonder what I did.

Comment: @jezrael Okay i'm going to post my own answer to this.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to below and there should not be any issues.

```
df1['EW'] = df1['EW'] + ' v ' + df1['WE']


df1['WE'] = df1['DA']
df1['DA'] = df1['DD']


df2['EW'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']


df2['EW'] = df2['AB'] + ' v ' + df2['AC']

df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='EW')
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'WE':'O1','AD':'O2'})
df3['D'] = df3['O2'].sub(df3['O1'], fill_value=0)
```